# Prevent m2m_changed from updating date modified of parent class

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class called Outfit and within the class, a many to many relationship called Products like this:

```
class Outfit(models.Model):
   products = models.ManyToManyField(Product,
                                  related_name='outfits',
                                  blank=True)
   created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
   modified = models.DateTimeField()

   class Meta:
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' On save, update timestamps '''
    if not self.id:
        self.created = timezone.now()
    self.modified = timezone.now()
    return super(Outfit, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have a variable called product_outfit_count in the products model which basically tracks how many outfits a particular product is used in. When an outfit is saved, this signal is called:

```
m2m_changed.connect(update_product_outfit_count,
                sender=Outfit.products.through)
```

The problem is, when a product's outfit count is updated, the date modified of the outfit changes as well. How can I prevent this?

EDIT:
update_product_count method:

```
def update_product_outfit_count_task(product_ids):
Product = apps.get_model('products.Product')
with transaction.atomic():
    for product in Product.objects.filter(pk__in=product_ids):
        product.outfit_count = product.outfits.count()
        product.save()
```

Comment: Post the method `update_product_outfit_count`.

Comment: @SachinKukreja posted

Comment: there is no `auto_now` argument passed to the `modified` field of the `Outfit` model. How are you exactly updating it when you actually need to?

Comment: @SachinKukreja, updated. I used auto_now previously but the results were the same. So I changed it to override save method; obviously didn't help

Comment: You maybe calling the `save` method when updating the products in the outfit. You dont need to.

Comment: @SachinKukreja, you mean I shouldn't be writing product.save()? How will the outfit_count be updated then?

Comment: No, not in the signal handler. I mean when you are changing the m2m_field on an `Outfit` model object. Probably, like this, outfit_obj.products.add(product), dont call `outfit.save`.

Comment: @SachinKukreja The problem is, the modified date of older outfits gets updated if, in a new outfit, I use a product that has already been used in an older outfit. I never call outfit.save() for older outfits when creating a new outfit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179318/discussion-between-cmwasiq-and-sachin-kukreja).